# Search Facebook Pages by Name and Location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to accurately search for a facebook page by name and location, so that I can then retrieve information on the page. For example, say that I'd like to search for an Allstate page in Haslet, TX (http://www.facebook.com/DixonInsurance). Since "Allstate" is in the page name it turns up in this search:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=allstate&type=page&limit=100&access_token=[your access token here]
```

It's great for getting a list of page ids for pages that contain "allstate" in the title, but there are an obscene number of those pages. In order to find the Allstate page that contains the city of Haslet, though, I have to barrage the facebook graph with irrelevant requests until I *finally* hit on [http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select name,page_url,location from page where page_id=365699213548](http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20name,page_url,location%20from%20page%20where%20page_id=365699213548). It's kind of like emptying a lake to get water for a drink - not to mention that the irrelevant requests go against facebook usage limitations.

I'm not looking for places, I am specifically looking for pages. Is there a way to add a city requirement to the opengraph request, or at least limit the number of pages I need to search through before locating the one I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to **[this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)** under `Searching`, take a close look at Places and Pages, additional parameters was mentioned for Places but not for pages, so may be you cannot have additional parameters to narrow down your search on Pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's the sense I get from what I've digested of the facebook graph, but there's a lot I could be missing since I don't have much experience working with it yet. Maybe someone with more experience working with the facebook graph can think of a way?